# Python: controlling processes with multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

### Background

I am implementing a program where I am able to start and end another process. I have used the sub-process module to implement (child) processes. I am using the Popen class to start another process.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

class Engine:
   def __init__(self):
    self.processes = list()

   def start_processes(self):
    self.processes.append(Popen(["python","producer.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE))
    self.processes.append(Popen(["python","consumer.py"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE))

   def end_processes(self):
    for process in self.processes:
        process.kill()

def handle_quit() -> bool:
   u_input = input("Quit?")
   if u_input != "q":
     return False
   else:
     return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialise quit flag
    quit_flag = False

    # Create engine
    app_engine = Engine()

    # Start processes
    app_engine.start_processes()

    # Handle input
    while not quit_flag:
        quit_flag = handle_quit()

    # Stop processes
    app_engine.end_processes()
```

### Problem

I'd like to be able to control all my sub-process within the engine class. I think this is the right way? Any other ideas?

Comment: You might look into the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module.

Comment: "Cuurently, its possible for only one of the sub-processes to run." In the code you've written? Both processes will be run in parallel, because the `Popen` constructor is non-blocking

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes my bad, I just checked their PID and you are right they are running in parallel. I will edit the post.